# DataFrame is it possible to scraping/Looking a key in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm studying Data Science and i have a problems with my data frame , can you help me? In my dataFrame i have 4 columns... 'Price', 'location', 'house with', 'description'.  in 'Price' and "house with" i have a few rows with Nan or without nothing. I really want to create a function that make a scraping in the column 'Description' , take a key(a word, for example: $40 or swimming pool, garden) and that keys transport to the columns 'price' or 'house with'.
example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Df2= {
    'Price': ['90','NaN','NaN',' '],
    'Location': ['NaN','Argentina','NaN','EEUU'],
    'House with': ['Swimming pool', 'Garden','NaN', 'NaN'],
    'Description': ['This house in Brazil cost $90 and       have swimming pool', 'his house in Argentina cost $50 and        have Garden','This house in Chile cost $70 and have Garden', 'This house in EEuu cost $80 and        have swimming pool']}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(Df2)
df3
```

and I would like it to be as follows

```
Df2= {
        'Price': ['90','50','70','80'],
        'Location': ['Brazil','Argentina','Chile','EEUU'],
        'House with': ['Swimming pool', 'Garden','Garden', 'swimming pool'],
        'Description': ['This house in Brazil cost $90 and       have swimming pool', 'his house in Argentina cost $50 and        have Garden','This house in Chile cost $70 and have Garden', 'This house in EEuu cost $80 and        have swimming pool']}
```

Comment: *I really want to create a function ...* What exactly keeps you from doing so? Please show us what you have tried so far and where it failed. Be specific about your problem.

Comment: @Binarus any function that i can put keywords like (swimming pool, Garden, or the price, with code regex) where this code takes these words of 'Description' and move these words in the corresponding row 'Price' or ' City' or 'House with'

Answer (score 1):

You can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) groups in string. If series has strings as follows:

```
df['Price'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'\$(\d+)')[0]
df['Location'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'house in ([A-Za-z]+)')[0]
df['House with'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'have ([A-Za-z]+)')[0]
df

 Price  Location    House with  Description
0   90    Brazil    swimming    This house in Brazil cost $90 and       have swimming pool
1   50 Argentina    Garden      his house in Argentina cost $50 and        have Garden
2   70     Chile    Garden      This house in Chile cost $70 and have Garden
3   80      EEuu    swimming    This house in EEuu cost $80 and        have swimming pool
```

Or

```
df['Price'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'\$(\d+)',expand=False)
df['Location'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'house in ([A-Za-z]+)',expand=False)
df['House with'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'have ([A-Za-z]+)',,expand=False)
```

Comment: what's the use of `[0]` at the end of `extract`?

Comment: @SaiKumar The Output by default a `dataframe` with column `0` (Since 1 Group). Also If it has more than 1 group then `1` column will be formed. Since we are working with `series` so taken out `0` column.